# views 3: select only one value from a multivalue field

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type which has a multivalue image field. I need to create a view that displays a list of nodes of that type but displays only one value of that multifield, not all of them.

I need to get something like this:

- node title
- first image

---

- node title
- first image

---

etc

Any ideas? Thanks, M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It under the "multiple field settings" in the settings of your image field.

You should choose "Display all values in the same row", separation mark: "", display 1 item, offset 0. (translated from my own language so names might be a bit different)

**UPDATE**
You will need to display fields rather then the whole node though. (I don't know how you did this before)

Comment: I was displaying fields but didn't look under the multiple field settings. This works as expected. thanks

Comment: I have found a fix somewhere too that allows you to display a random item from a list (there is nothing to do that in drupal or views), but I can't trace it back. So you are are on your own there...

Comment: I believe it was the last one from here: http://drupal.org/node/1190900 (it failed the auto-test but is safe to use)